# ¿Como puedo obtener el mayor precio de un objeto teniendo en cuenta un año introducido por el usuario en una aplicación de java con mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

Este código es el como lo tengo implementado en java:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("last_scraped", 2017)), Aggregates.group("_id", cumulators.max("max", "$price"))));
```

En mongo me gustaría hacer uso de una sentencia similar a la siguiente:

```
db.listings_detail.aggregate([ {$match: {{$year: "$last_scraped"}: 2017}}, {$group: {_id: {max: {$max: "$price"}}}} ])
```

Comment: Por favor, eso que escribes en el comentario agrégalo a la pregunta haciendo clic en [edit]. También sería de utilidad que indicaras el tipo de campo y la estructura relevante del documento en tu colección. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia en mongo para la resolución de esta duda me la han respondido en el siguiente enlace:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626887/13830122

El resumen de su respuesta es el uso de expresiones regulares en el metodo find()

```
db.getCollection('listings_detail').find({"last_scraped": {"$regex": ".*2017$"} }).sort(price: -1).limit(1)
```